# handle multiple ajax on a single PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a `js` switch declaration that checks if a specific string is present in the submitted text.

```
var textA= //regex
var textB= //regex

switch(true) {
  case textA.test(input):
    // CASE A
      $ajax ({
        type:"post",
        url:"process.php",
        data: {input:input,age:age,city:city,type:type},
        success: function(html){alert(html);} });
      break;
  case textB.test(input):
    // CASE B
      $ajax ({
        type:"post",
        url:"process.php",
        data: {input:input,width:width,height:height,type:type},
        success: function(html){alert(html);} });
      break;
 case ...
 }
```

normally, i would create dedicated `php` file to handle the POST data for each of `$ajax`.

but how can i handle multiple `$ajax` POST in a single `php`.

i included a unique identifier `type:` for each ajax data, this will be my reference as to what ajax is being received by my PHP

but im not sure how to properly code PHP to handle the submitted $_POST type.

```
<?php
      //get post type from submitted AJAX
      $type = $_POST;

      switch($type) {
        case 0:
          $type= "caseA"
          //some code here
        case 1:
          $type= "caseB"
          // some code here
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: It should be $type = $_POST["type"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send an action per case,

e.g.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'path/to/file.php',
   type: 'POST / GET',
   data: {action: 1, data:myObject}
});
```

Every case, send a different action, then in PHP check that with `$_POST / $_GET['action']`

so you can do a `switch` statement

e.g.

```
switch($_POST / $_GET['action']) {
   case 1:
       //do something
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
switch(true) {
  case textA.test(input):
    // CASE A
      $ajax ({
        type:"post",
        url:"process.php",
        data: {input:input,age:age,city:city,type:"typeA"},
        success: function(html){alert(html);} });
      break;
  case textB.test(input):
    // CASE B
      $ajax ({
        type:"post",
        url:"process.php",
        data: {input:input,width:width,height:height,type:"typeB"},
        success: function(html){alert(html);} });
      break;
 case ...
 }
```

And then in PHP:

```
<?php

  switch($_POST['type']) { // or $_REQUEST['type']
    case 'typeA':
      // Type A handling code here
      break;
    case 'typeB':
      // Type B handling code here
      break;
  }
```